# Problems with ApiController in Blazor App

Tags: c#, api, async-await, blazor

So I'm wracking my brain here. I have a Blazor Server App that I've created, and to it I've added a few ApiControllers. I am getting what seems to me to be strange errors, only with the production environment. For some reason the Request.Body is being disposed before I ever get to read it. I've tried reading with a StreamReader, copying into a new MemoryStream, what's weird is, it will work for maybe a dozen requests, then stops working and starts throwing either "Reading not allowed after stream is completed" or "IFeatureCollection has been disposed" errors. I can get it to work flawlessly in debug mode with IIS Express in VS. But it will not work consistently on IIS server. Oddly enough, it WILL work consistently when calls are sent with Postman. Just really odd. So basically what I have as an example is, an ApiController, ProfileController, and it just has 1 POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public async void Post()
{
   String bodyContent = String.Empty;
   using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
   {
      bodyContent = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
   // use body content xml, generate response xml
   String responseXML = "ResponseText";
   Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
   Response.WriteAsync(responseXML);
}
```

So I get errors some times when reading the request stream above, sometimes that works then I get an error that the Response has been disposed when I try to set ContentType

Is there something about Blazor that is consuming the Request/Response streams ahead of the API routing? This just really baffles me.

Comment: ok so I got it to work in a dirty way, by enabling synchronous IO and using ReadToEnd() but Id still like to get it right so that the async method works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// public async void Post()
   public async Task Post()
```

`async void` methods are not awaitable, the aspnet framework has no way of knowing that your action is still running and returns the response immediately.

> what seems to me to be strange errors

Yes, it can accidentally succeed. Threading and asynchrony errors can be very undeterministic.

Comment: Every time someone uses `async void` a fairy dies.

Comment: Welp, that was easy, seems I killed another fairy!